# Create a script to run multiple java jar in different terminal windows

Tags: java, bash, shell, jar

I wrote an application in java that needs five players and a server.
I need to write a script that executes the jar of the server and of every single player in different terminal windows. How can I do?

I tried a script and worked but the jar opened in the same terminal window than I tried with xterm or konsole with flag `--noclose` but does not work (`warning command: konsole not found`)

```sh
#! /bin/sh
xterm  --hold -e java -jar /Users/Marco\ 1/Documents/ing-sw-2019-Lentini-Marazzi-Marini/out/artifacts/server_jar/adrenalina.jar 

for X in $(seq 5)

do

  konsole --noclose  -e java -jar  /Users/Marco\ 1/Documents/ing-sw-2019-Lentini-Marazzi-Marini/out/artifacts/client_jar/adrenalina.jar gui 

done

exit;
```

Comment: You might want to do some research about [tag:tmux] and/or [tag:screen]

Answer (score -1):

To run a process in the background from `bash`, you'll need to add an `&` to the end of your command, e.g.

```
java -jar /path/to/jar/my.jar &
```

Otherwise `bash` will wait until the command execution terminates.

Comment: I have already tried with the & but did work only in the same terminal window, I need to launch these jars in different terminal windows, this is my problem

Comment: If your programs are command-line, then you would do the same thing but execute the terminal, instructing it to execute your jar, as you have done. Assuming you have konsole installed, and in your PATH, you should be able to run it from your script like you tried.